# Build array from jenkins parameters

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to build an array from a parameterized jenkins build?

I have tried the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin which allows me to create a single title with multiple options within it. So I build a extended choice called services with 5 services listed as check boxes.

However when I try to do a loop over what I thought would be an array `${services[@]}` I just get the single value of comma separated values. I tried setting `IFS=','` and that does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This just doesn't work with check boxes. If you use a text field and specify each variable there it will loop as if it were a true array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array first from Jenkins multiple choice variable:

```
IFS=',' read -r -a services <<< "$services"

for service in ${services[@]}; do
    echo "$service"
done
```